# Magento - Display higher price for product

Tags: php, magento

It is evident that Magento always displays the lowest price of the original price, special price, etc.

I have a condition where I have to display the customer specific price that comes from an ERP system. Let's call it special price. If that special price is higher than the product's price, Magento obviously chooses the least one.

The question, is there any way to override this in a smooth way? Because regardless of the products' price, the requirement is to display the customer specific price from the ERP system on Magento.If there is no customer specific price available, it is OK to fallback to the products' price.

Comment: If a product has a price in the ERP and must sell at that price... why would you even have a special price, etc. in Magento? Can't you just empty those fields?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Override

> Mage_Catalog_Model_Product_Type_Price

Check Customer specific price against Products price and Do the logic